# Org mode diary intergration is showing a mashed up mess from Zoom invitations

Tags: org-mode, mu4e, diary

I recently got excorporate working to pull in zoom meetings into org agenda. The result is less than appealing (personal details scribbed)

```
Week-agenda (W18):
Monday      3 May 2021 W18
  tasks:      Scheduled:  NEXT Submit PCR Bias
Tuesday     4 May 2021
Wednesday   5 May 2021
Thursday    6 May 2021
               8:00...... ----------------
              10:00...... ----------------
              12:00...... ----------------
  Diary:      13:00-14:00 Dean's Town Hall Faculty Meeting; Desc: XXX is inviting you to a scheduled Zoom meeting.; Topic: Dean's Town Hall Faculty Meeting; Time: Jan 14, 2021 01:30 PM Eastern Time (US and Canada); Jan 14, 2021 01:30 PM; Jan 28, 2021 01:00 PM; Feb 11, 2021 01:00 PM; Feb 25, 2021 01:00 PM; Mar 11, 2021 01:00 PM; Mar 25, 2021 01:00 PM; Apr 8, 2021 01:00 PM; Apr 22, 2021 01:00 PM; May 6, 2021 01:00 PM; May 20, 2021 01:00 PM; Please download and import the following iCalendar (.ics) files to your calendar system.; Weekly: https://XXX.zoom.us/meeting/Join from PC, Mac, Linux, iOS or Android: https://.zoom.us/j/99417454933?pwd=dFl6ZFh; Password: 9; Or iPhone one-tap (US Toll):  +16468769,99417454933#  or +13017158592,9#; Or Telephone:; Dial:; +1 646 876 9923 (US Toll); +1 301 715 85(US Toll); +1 312 626 6799 (US Toll); +1 669 900 6833 (US Toll); +1 253 215 8782 (US Toll); +1 346 248 7799 (US ); Meeting ID: 1745 4933; Password: ; International numbers available: https://.zoom.us/u/adqxOH5XpX; Or an H.323/SIP room system:; H.323:; 162.255.37.11 (US West); 162.255.36.11 (US East); 221.122.88.195 (China); 115.114.131.7 (India Mumbai); 115.114.115.7 (India Hyderabad); 213.19.144.110 (Amsterdam Netherlands); 213.244.140.110 (Germany); 103.122.166.55 (Australia); 209.9.211.110 (Hong Kong SAR)
              14:00...... ----------------
              16:00...... ----------------
              18:00...... ----------------
              20:00...... ----------------
              21:05...... now - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  tasks:      In   5 d.:  TODO [#A] Figure out pay for summer
  tasks:      Sched. 3x:  NEXT Submit PCR Bias
  tasks:      Scheduled:  TODO Collect Soil Samples
  tasks:      Scheduled:  NEXT Pay water bill
  tasks:      Scheduled:  TODO Reply to Pedro
  tasks:      In   1 d.:  TODO Order Flowers
  tasks:      In   1 d.:  TODO Fill out Training Grant Info
  tasks:      In  14 d.:  TODO Complete Proposal Information Form
  Diary:      xx.xxx.xxx.xxx (Brazil)
  Diary:      xx.xxx.xx.xxx (Canada); 20x10 (Japan); Meeting ID: 99x;1; SIP: 933@zoomcrc.com<mailto:99@zoomcrc.com>; Password:971; Location: httzoom.us/j994x49cd: 9; Organizer: mailto:@..edu
Friday      7 May 2021
  calendar:   11:00-12:00 Biweekly Meeting on Microbiome Stats (Zoom)
  Diary:      11:00-12:00 Biweekly Meeting on Microbiome Stats; Desc: https://.zoom.us/j/; Location: Zoom; Organizer: mailto:xxx@asdf.edu
```

Note, this is acctually one meeting that is being garbled into one really long meeting title at 1pm today. And for some reason also showing up numerous times later on in the day due to, I guess, an IP address in Brazil and Canada being picked up as tasks? Meetings? I am not sure.

Is there some easy way to fix this? Or some regex that I can use to format diary entries in the org mode agenda.

Here is what the header of that meeting in Diary looks like:

```
Thursday, May 6, 2021
=====================
13:00-14:00 Dean's Town Hall Faculty Meeting
 Desc: XXX is inviting you to a scheduled Zoom meeting.
 
 Topic: Dean's Town Hall Faculty Meeting
 Time: Jan 14, 2021 01:30 PM Eastern Time (US and Canada)
     Jan 14, 2021 01:30 PM

     May 20, 2021 01:00 PM
     Please download and import the following iCalendar (.ics) files to your calendar system.
     Weekly: https://XXX.zoom.us/meeting/tJ0pdCdFeJGGaQrFM7U
 
 Join from PC, Mac, Linux, iOS or Android: https://XXX.zoom.us/j/99
     Password: asdf
 
 Or iPhone one-tap (US Toll):  +164687697454933#  or +1301754933#
 
 Or Telephone:
     Dial:
     +1(US Toll)
     Meeting ID:
     International numbers available: https://XXX.zoom.us/u/adpX
```

Alternatively, if there is just a better way of going about this entire endeavor I am wide open to that. I really just want my calendar and meetings to show up in agenda.

Comment: What exactly do you want the agenda to show? `org-agenda-get-entries-from-diary` is the function that retrieves the entries and makes them available to the agenda: it basically produces a "fancy" diary display and scrapes the entries from that. You may be able to give it an after-advice to do something with that data, or even redefine that function according to your needs.

Comment: I basically just want to see that first line in the agenda - the rest I would like to be able to see if I press RET and follow to the original diary entry.